# Erro em algoritmo de calendario da pascoa

Tags: python, data

Estava mexendo com ums programas que calculam datas, porem achei um algoritmo em python muito preciso que me retorna corretamente o dia que vai cair e que ja caiu o feriado da pascoa.

O algoritmo em python é este:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8
#você pode modificar o codigo e distribuir a vontade, desde quee
#nao retire o nome do Autor
#Autor: Luis Eduardo Boiko Ferreira
#e-mail: luiseduardo.boiko@gmail.com
import time
import datetime 
print ' _______________________________________'
print '|                                       |'
print '|                                       |'
print '|       Algoritmo para calcular         |'
print '|          o dia da Pascoa              |'
print '|          Desenvolvido por             |'
print '|      Luis Eduardo Boiko Ferreira      |'
print '|_______________________________________|'
anoatual = datetime.date.today().year 
print 'O ano atual é %s.' %anoatual
ano=input('Digite o ano desejado para calcularmos o dia da páscoa: ')
a=int(ano%19)
b=int(ano/100)
c=int(ano%100)
d=int(b/4)
e=int(b%4)
f=int((b+8)/25)
g=int((b-f+1)/3)
h=((19*a+b-d-g+15)%30)
i=int(c/4)
k=int(c%4)
L=((32+2*e+2*i-h-k)%7)
m=int((a+11*h+22*L)/451)
mes=int((h+L-7*m+114)/31)
if mes==1 : mes='Janeiro'
elif mes==2 : mes='Fevereiro'
elif mes==3 : mes='Março'
elif mes==4 : mes='Abril'
elif mes==5 : mes='Maio'
elif mes==6 : mes='Junho'
elif mes==7 : mes='Julho'
elif mes ==8 : mes ='Agosto'
elif mes ==9 : mes ='Setembro'
elif mes ==10 : mes ='Outubro'
elif mes ==11 : mes ='Novembro'
else : mes ='Dezembro'
mes1=mes
dia=(((h+L-7*m+114)%31)+1)
if anoatual>ano :
  print "A pascoa caiu no dia: %s."% dia 
  print "Do mês: %s" %mes1

else :
   print "A pascoa ira cair no dia: %s."% dia 
   print "Do mês: %s" %mes1
```

Fui converter o mesmo para c++ mas está me dando erro.

> pascoa.cxx:79:18: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

meu algoritmo convertido é este:

```
#include <iostream>
//http://www.webcid.com.br/calendario/2018/brasil

int main()
{

time_t now = time(0);
tm *ltm = localtime(&now);

int anoatual = ltm->tm_year+1900;


printf("O ano atual é %4d.", anoatual);

int ano;

printf("Digite o ano desejado para calcularmos o dia da páscoa: ");
scanf("%d", &ano);

int a=(ano%19);
int b=int(ano/100);
int c=(ano%100);
int d=int(b/4);
int e=(b%4);
int f=int((b+8)/25);
int g=int((b-f+1)/3);
int h=((19*a+b-d-g+15)%30);
int i=int(c/4);
int k=(c%4);

int L=((32+2*e+2*i-h-k)%7);
int m=int((a+11*h+22*L)/451);
int mes=int((h+L-7*m+114)/31);

if (mes == 1){
  (char)mes='Janeiro';
}
else 
if(mes == 2){
  (char)mes='Fevereiro';
}
else
if(mes == 3){
  (char)mes='Março';
}
else
if(mes == 4){
  (char)mes='Abril';
}
else
if(mes == 5){
    (char)mes='Maio';
}
else
if(mes == 6){
  (char)mes='Junho';
}
else
if(mes == 7){
  (char)mes='Julho';
}
else
if(mes == 8){
  (char)mes ='Agosto';
}
else
if(mes == 9){
  (char)mes ='Setembro';
}
else
if(mes == 10){
  (char)mes ='Outubro';
}
else
if(mes == 11){
  (char)mes ='Novembro';
}
else
if(mes ==12){
(char)mes ='Dezembro';
}

char mes1=(char)mes;

int dia=((h+L-7*m+114)%31)+1;

if (anoatual>ano)
{
  printf("A pascoa caiu no dia: %s.",&dia); 
  printf("Do mês: %s", &mes1);
}
else
if (anoatual<ano)
{
  printf("A pascoa ira cair no dia: %s.",&dia); 
  printf("Do mês: %s", &mes1);
}
 return 0;
}
```

portanto de acordo com este site:
http://www.webcid.com.br/calendario/2018/brasil

o algoritmo em python esta calculando precisamente os dias qual é o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns pontos no seu código convertido que precisa de corrigir:

- `mes='Janeiro'`

  O delimitador para strings são as aspas duplas `"` e por isso a sua atribuição dos meses não está correta e deveria ser `mes="Janeiro";`. A aspa simples `'` por vezes chamada de plica é utiliza para o tipo `char` de apenas um caractere.

  Para além disso está a atribuir o valor para uma variável do tipo inteiro:

  ```
  int mes=...;
  ...
  mes='Janeiro';
  ```

  Logo nunca iria funcionar. Lembre-se que em C uma variável é definida com um tipo e não pode alterar ao contrario do python.
- `printf("A pascoa caiu no dia: %s.",&dia);` O `printf` não leva `&` que é o operador para obter o endereço de memoria da variável. Apenas o `scanf` e caso a variável já não seja um ponteiro.

Em C ou C++ tem uma estrutura que pode utilizar diferente para muitos ifs encadeados que é o `switch` que lhe permite organizar mais o código. Combinando isso com a correção dos erros, poderia ficar assim:

```
//resto para cima igual
int mes=int((h+L-7*m+114)/31); //esta ainda igual também

char* mes1 = "Mês inválido"; //aqui nova variável para o texto do mes

switch (mes){ //agora com switch em vez de ifs
    case 1: mes1 = "Janeiro"; break;
    case 2: mes1 = "Fevereiro"; break;
    case 3: mes1 = "Março"; break;
    case 4: mes1 = "Abril"; break;
    case 5: mes1 = "Maio"; break;
    case 6: mes1 = "Junho"; break;
    case 7: mes1 = "Julho"; break;
    case 8: mes1 = "Agosto"; break;
    case 9: mes1 = "Setembro"; break;
    case 10: mes1 = "Outubro"; break;
    case 11: mes1 = "Novembro"; break;
    case 12: mes1 = "Dezembro"; break;
}

int dia=((h+L-7*m+114)%31)+1;

if (anoatual>ano) { //printfs agora sem &
    printf("A pascoa caiu no dia: %d.",dia);
    printf("Do mês: %s", mes1);
}
else if (anoatual<ano) { //printfs agora sem &
    printf("A pascoa ira cair no dia: %d.",dia);
    printf("Do mês: %s", mes1);
}
```

Repare que cada caso do `switch`, que corresponde a cada um dos `if`s que tinha necessita de ter o `break` para estar correto.

Note também que o tipo utilizado para representar um texto foi um `char*` que poderá ser um `char[]` dependendo da forma como é utilizado, e que representa um array de caracteres. Pode também utilizar o tipo `string` que na maior parte dos casos simplifica, sendo necessário incluir a biblioteca correspondente, que para C++ seria `<cstring>`.

Comment: entao eu até tinha tentado usar aspas duplas só mudei, char* mes1 = "Mês inválido";  para const char* mes1 = "Mês inválido";  porem achei que mesmo a variavel sento uma variavel inteira achei que se eu usasse (char)minhavar="message"; ele deveria retornar a string nela nao deveria? em relação ao & no printf foi descuido meu e falta de atenção depois que eu postei que fui ver..

Comment: @dark777 Nem por isso. E a conversão o `(char)` tem de vir a direita tipo assim `minhavar = (char)"message"` mas também não irá funcionar pois `"message"` é um ponteiro e não um `char`, ou seja é um pouco mais complicado. Transitar de python ou qualquer outra linguagem para C vai ser mais complicado devido principalmente a ponteiros e memória. E por isso a minha recomendação final é que estude particularmente essa parte.

Comment: entao eu fiz isso nao foi pq eu quis imitar a conversao de python no c++, acontece que um dia desses eu vi um programa que tinha uma função que recebia um inteiro mas dava retorno de char portando a função pegava a variavel inteira e fazia: return (char)variavel; e variavel era inteira...

Comment: @dark777 Dá perfeitamente para fazer, e converte um número para o caractere correspondente utilizando a tabela ascii. Eu não há muito tempo respondi a uma pergunta utilizando isso. Mas convém reparar que é converter para um `char` e não um `char*`, e o tipo que está a converter é um `int` e não um `char*` como no seu caso.

Comment: entao pelo que entendi isso só poderia ser feito com um unico caractere...

Comment: @dark777 Sim as conversões funcionam entre tipos específicos e para `char` só dá para um único caractere. Exemplos de conversões desse género `int x = (int)'A';` em que `x` ficava com 65. Ou `char c = (char)65;` em que `c` ficava com letra `A`

Comment: legal valeu pelas explicaçoes..